# Proof by resolution - showing there is no contradiction

Tags: computer-science

For simpler questions involving proof by resolution, it is easy to see whether or not a contradiction can be found by inferring the empty clause, and somewhat easy to show there is no empty clause inference. However, for questions involving a larger number of clauses and terms, such as:

$a ∨ b ∨ c \\
a ∨ ¬c ∨ d \\
¬a ∨ e ∨ f \\
c ∨ ¬e ∨ f \\ 
c ∨ ¬d ∨ ¬f $

How exactly, using a formal method, can we show that an empty clause cannot be inferred?

Comment: Case distinction?

Comment: What do you mean? Try every possible case?

Comment: In a clever way, of course, but yes. That is sometimes the best way to go, like "case 1: $a = 0$, case 1a $b \neq 0$,...". It doesn't look as elegant as other proofs, but it is a systematic way to get things done.

Comment: Checking that the set of clauses is *satisfiable*. Set $a= \text T$ and the two first clauses are sat. Then with $f= \text T$ also the third and fourth are. And it's done.